# Postgresql problem with similar to and pattern behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came to a standstill with a relatively trivial issue.
Such a simple query:

```
select distinct field_name,length(field_name) from table_a where
field_name similar to `2\[0-9\]\[0-9\]%`;
```

returns the following rows:

```
field_name|length|
----------+------+
200       |     3|
203       |     3|
210       |     3|
```

But the very similar one, where only '%' in the expression has been omitted returns no rows:

```
  select distinct field_name,length(field_name) from table_a where 
         field_name similar to  '[23][0-9][0-2]';
```

The `field_name` column is defined as `CHAR(10)`.
The problem probably results from some characters at the end of the field but I don't know how to eliminate them.
Would you mind telling me how to solve it?

Checked postgresql documentation and tutorials,
searched on google and stackoverflow without success.

Comment: The issue might be arising due to trailing spaces in your field_name column. Since it's defined as CHAR(10), if the data in the column doesn't utilize all 10 characters, the database will fill the remaining characters with spaces, which could interfere with your regular expression matching.

Comment: That cannot be. First you are using backticks instead of single quotes in the query you claim to return results, an then `\[` matches a literal opening bracket, so the pattern will not match the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick guess: In the first query you are using the % Wildcard. So the char must not be exactly 3 digits long. Maybe there are some trailing spaces in your data?

Try something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_name, LENGTH(field_name)
FROM table_a
WHERE TRIM(field_name) SIMILAR TO '[23][0-9][0-2]'
```

Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Exactly, your tip worked perfectly,  and I can't stop wondering why I've forgotten about the trim function.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  field_name CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_a (field_name) VALUES 
('200       '), 
('203       '), 
('210       '), 
('230       '), 
('250       ');

INSERT INTO table_a (field_name) VALUES 
('200'), 
('203'), 
('210'), 
('230'), 
('250');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 5
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 5
> ```

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_name, LENGTH(field_name) 
FROM table_a 
WHERE field_name SIMILAR TO '[23][0-9][0-2]'
```

| field_name | length |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(field_name), LENGTH(TRIM(field_name)) 
FROM table_a 
WHERE TRIM(field_name) SIMILAR TO '[23][0-9][0-2]'
```

| btrim | length |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 3 |
| 210 | 3 |
| 230 | 3 |
| 250 | 3 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uA39et7g)